# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'rejectWithValue' of 'thunkAPI' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

I am following a tutorial with this code:

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { Axios } from "axios";

export const getData = createAsyncThunk("data/get", async (thunkAPI) => {
  try {
    const response = await Axios.get("/data");
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    const { rejectWithValue } = thunkAPI;
    return rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
  }
});
```

I read the documentation but apparently there shouldn't be anything wrong with this code. Still, I am getting the error that `rejectWithValue` is undefined. So what is the problem? Do I have install some package? Or has the notation changed?

Answer (score 0):

The `thunkAPI` is the ***second*** argument to the asynchronous action's [payloadCreator](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#payloadcreator) you are creating. The first argument is any value that is passed to the action when it's dispatched. If you aren't passing any value you still need to "assign" it to a local variable so you can access the *second* argument, "thunkAPI". You can use any valid Javascript identifier you like, but it is a standard convention to assign the argument to `_` to indicate it is "unused". Naming it `arg` may make it more readable.

Example:

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { Axios } from "axios";

export const getData = createAsyncThunk(
  "data/get",
  async (arg, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const { data } = await Axios.get("/data");
      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      const { rejectWithValue } = thunkAPI;
      return rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
    }
  },
);
```